# Disable tap event on transparent part of image in WP7/WP8

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, image-processing, windows-phone-8

I am using some transparent images in my Windows phone project.
Let Say My Origanal Image Size is 400 x 100.

[image: Original Image]

After slicing images into four different parts it looks like this. First arrow is active and rest part is transparent but the image size is same 400 x 100. And I do the same for all rest three arrows. I sliced them for active part and while rest part will be transparent and size will be 400 x 100. So when I place all 4 images in grid it will show like above image.

[image: Image After Slicing But Its Same in Width, One Part is active and other part is transparent]

I want to get tap event of each image. Is there any way I can just get the tap event of active part mean which have some value mean color value not transparent area or inactive part of image. Mean once I click on First image it will give me event of that image. And when I tap on second image it will give me tap event of second image. But When I click on image it gives me only 1 tap event as its taking the full width and height and other images are also in same size. Please suggest any work around for that.

Comment: any particular reason why you are not using 4 100x100 images?

Comment: @Riho: Yes, Actually this is very general picture, In my actual project there will be 100 or more slices for one picture. If I set same size for each slice and just crop active area whom tap event I require while the rest part will be transparent. Once I add these images in my container it will form as actual image without giving hardcoded margins. I hope you got my point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XAML

```
<Grid Name="Grid1">
    <Image Tag="Image1" Source="1.png"/>
    <Image Tag="Image2" Source="2.png"/>
    <!-- more images -->
</Grid>
```

CS

```
void MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs args)
{
    foreach (var img in ((Panel)sender).Children.OfType<Image>())
    {
        var w = new WriteableBitmap(img, null);
        var p = args.GetPosition(img);
        if (w.Pixels[w.PixelWidth * (int)p.Y + (int)p.X] != 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("You clicked {0}!", img.Tag));
            args.Handled = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Attach handler like this

```
Grid1.AddHandler(UIElement.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent,
    new MouseButtonEventHandler(MouseDown), false);
```

Namespaces

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
```

Comment: A Bunch Of Thanks To You. You Did Splendid Job And Its Works Like Charm. Really Appreciated :)

Comment: I think it should be  
`var w = new WriteableBitmap(img, null);
var p = args.GetPosition(img);
if (p.X >= w.PixelWidth || p.Y >= w.PixelHeight)
{
continue;
}
`
to avoid out of boundaries exception if the images have different sizes or different margins.